# Django + Apache2 + Ubuntu + WSGI + sqlite3 - attempt to write a readonly database. How to fix?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

I know there are tons of questions like this here, on SO, but absolutely nothing worked for me.

As the title says, I am trying to configure my Django app using Apache2 and mod_wsgi. Unfortunately, when I try to log into the app:

```
OperationalError at /3gjTaZ446V/admin/login/
attempt to write a readonly database
```

---

## Details:

1. I'm logged in as `root`.
2. My config looks like this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName test.domain.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/3gjTaZ446V

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/3gjTaZ446V_error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/3gjTaZ446V_access.log combined

       Alias /static /var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie/static/
       <Directory /var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie/static>
               Require all granted
       </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie/logs/>
               Require all granted
       </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie>
           <Files db.sqlite3>
               Require all granted
           </Files>
       </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie/config>
           <Files wsgi.py>
               Require all granted
           </Files>
       </Directory>

       WSGIDaemonProcess 3gjTaZ446V python-home=/var/www/.virtualenvs/3gjTaZ446V python-path=/var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie
       WSGIProcessGroup 3gjTaZ446V
       WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/3gjTaZ446V/mips_geonomie/config/wsgi.py
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. The permissions on my project root:

   ```
   $ ls -altr

   total 184
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root       4096 Aug 19 09:44 ..
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       4096 Aug 19 09:44 requirements
   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root        538 Aug 19 09:44 manage.py
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root        200 Aug 19 09:45 .env
   drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       4096 Aug 19 09:45 config
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root www-data   4096 Aug 19 09:45 logs
   drwxr-xr-x 5 root root       4096 Aug 19 09:45 api
   drwxr-xr-x 6 root root       4096 Aug 19 09:45 static
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data 131072 Aug 19 09:45 db.sqlite3
   ```

I tried to change the permissions of db.sqlite3 to 644, 755, 777... nothing works. I also tried to `chown :www-data` and nothing.

I'm really out of ideas. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmmmm...looks like you need to setup a new user that isn't root...or you may have to restart the server with the new permissions in place...

Comment: Both the database file and the directory it is in need to be writable by user that Apache run as. Better to stick your database file in a different directory and make that directory owned by Apache user. Don't use ``o+w`` as is bad practice.